# Nan columns not dropping

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have the data-set that contains some NAN values. i tried this to drop it but it is still showing

```
df['string_tweet'].dropna(inplace=True)
df['string_tweet']
```

this is the output

```
113                        apc started let ’ finish started
235       upon vote katsina , apc government left state ...
1796      two people contesting office , one person win ...
1798      deji said peter obi jumping church church.na d...
1850      amnesia set , lem say deleting incriminating p...
                                ...                        
378726                                                  nan
378727                                                  nan
378728                                                  nan
378729                                                  nan
378730                                                  nan
Name: string_tweet, Length: 63664, dtype: object
```

please check the length and the row, they are not corresponding

Comment: are you sure you have `NaN`? it could be that you have strings that say `"nan"`. Pandas shows usually NaN values as `NaN` not `nan`

Comment: you're calling dropna on a series in a dataframe. i don't think this will effect the original dataframe, at least it's not clear to me what that should do. you can dropna on the dataframe, but that will effect other columns as well.

Comment: The length and the rows are not corresponding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proper NaN values, use the subset argument to work on the whole dataframe:

```
df.dropna(subset=['string_tweet'], inplace=True)
```

If your dataframe includes `"nan"` strings as suggested by @99_m4n, you may filter them out using:

```
df = df[df['string_tweet']!='nan']
```

Comment: Still the same, the length and the rows are not corresponding, check the output i posted please

Comment: that does not matter here.

Comment: Does `df = df[df['string_tweet']!='nan']` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that the pictured `nan` are of type `numpy.ndarray` try to convert your column before droping the NaN.

```
df['string_tweet']=df['string_tweet'].astype(float)
```